# why cannot i upload an image to an upload input button using selenium? It works fine when opened manually but why doesn't it work through selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have an input button that demands an image upload. The html code looks something like this:

`<input type="file" name="files" data-file="" data-url="../upload/student/image" accept="image/*">`

since the button opens a windows screen from where we can upload the image, i also tried using robot class but The button is not being clicked somehow.

```
WebElement upload= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"student_image\"]/input[1]"));
    upload.click();
    Robot robot= new Robot();
    StringSelection string= new 
    StringSelection("C:\\Users\\pradi\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\outline\\RHEST\\avatar.jpg");
    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(string,null);
    robot.setAutoDelay(1000);
    Ctrl+V(Pressed)
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
    Ctrl+V(Released)
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
    robot.setAutoDelay(2000);
    //Press Enter
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

It is showing error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException: invalid argument
  (Session info: chrome=83.0.4103.61)
Session ID: 28dd9e0fbe4ec0e77ba63ac627a7696f at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:285)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.click(RemoteWebElement.java:84)
    at student.student_form.adding_student(student_form.java:105)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:133)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:584)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:172)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:46)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:804)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:145)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1249)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:770)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:591)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:402)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:396)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:355)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:304)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1180)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1102)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1032)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1000)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
```

Just to find out the the exact point where my code stopped working i tried println in each lines, and found out that from this line `upload.click();` the code wasn't working
I'm using chrome Version 83.0.4103.61

Answer (score 0):

Instead of;

```
upload.click();
```

Use;

```
uploadElement.sendKeys("path_to_image//example_image.png");
```

Comment: yes, i did try that aswell. When i used that, it moved further without showing any error but it didn't show any result.Nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

You can join waiting

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"student_image\"]/input[1]"))
.sendKeys(C:\\Users\\pradi\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\outline\\RHEST\\avatar.jpg);
```

Please confirm xpath and Is there an iframe